# Why doesn't my image load on firefox browser but loads on safari/chrome?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering why my image doesn't load on a firefox browser but loads on safari/chrome?

```css
.shape {
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: #4D5061;
      content: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg);
      color: white;
      height: 300px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 300px;
      top: 15%;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -150px;
      z-index: 10;
      }
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: What does the "Network" tab in Firefox developer tools show for the request to get the image?

Comment: Any reason why you are using the `content` css property here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `background-image` instead. As on [Mozilla support page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

> The **content** CSS property is used with the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements to generate content in an element.

```css
.shape {
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: #4D5061;
      background-image: url('http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg');
      color: white;
      height: 300px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 300px;
      top: 15%;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -150px;
      z-index: 10;
      }
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your CSS to this. Don't use `content` for a background image because there's a much easier way to do it. Try this instead using the [**background shorthand**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background) (you can also just use `background-image` too).

```css
.shape {
      border-radius: 25px;
      background: url(http://i1126.photobucket.com/albums/l611/ldocherty1/IMG_0730_zpsiz4dqc47.jpg) center no-repeat #4D5061;
      color: white;
      height: 300px;
      margin: auto;
      padding: 3px;
      width: 300px;
      top: 15%;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -150px;
      z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Historically the `content` property [was only defined for pseudo-elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content). Firefox's current implementation only supports this use case.

For example,

```
.foo::before {
  content: 'hi';
}
```

would work. Usage on real elements like in the question,

```
.foo {
  content: 'hi';
}
```

currently does not work in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, by doing this:

```
.shape, .shape:after {
   content: url('path');
}
```

Works for Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Theonly thing is to take care to remove the `alt` attribute from the `img` or you will see the `alt` value and the actual image in Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

.shape::before{ content:url("link");}